# перемещение файлов python

Tags: python

помогите пожалуйста Я уже что только не перепробовал.
Представьте: Каждый день приходит архив с вчерашним числом там 3 папки "OBI_H", "OBI_R", "OBI_V" в каждой из них есть файлы без расширения их нужно переместить в другие папки,как это сделать?

Вот первый пример кода:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import patoolib
import os


today = datetime.now()
yesterday = today - timedelta(1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

path = 'D:/doc/ARHIW/'
rf = path + yesterday + '.rar'
in_dir = 'D:/doc/ARHIW/' + yesterday + '/' 'IN/'
patoolib.extract_archive(rf, outdir=in_dir)

in_obih = os.listdir(in_dir + yesterday + '/OBI_H.BANK')
in_obir = os.listdir(in_dir + yesterday + '/OBI_R.BANK')
in_obiw = os.listdir(in_dir + yesterday + '/OBI_W.BANK')
in_obr = os.listdir(in_dir + yesterday + '/OBR')
in_ooo = os.listdir(in_dir + yesterday + '/OSV_OSL_OAR')

mf_in_obir = in_dir + 'OBI_R.BANK/'
mf_in_obis = in_dir + 'OBI_S.BANK/'
mf_in_obiv = in_dir + 'OBI_V.BANK/'
mf_in_obr = in_dir + 'OBR_OBI/'
mf_in_osvs = in_dir + 'OSV_S.BANK/'

for f in in_obih:
    os.rename(f, mf_in_obis)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос две ваши попытки решить задачу. Мы поможем довести их до ума.

Comment: `yesterday` уже присутствует в `in_dir` тут  `in_obih = os.listdir(in_dir + yesterday` он добавляется повторно, не уверен что ошибка именно в этом, но выглядит странно

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос сформулирован так что вряд ли может быть полезен кому либо другому на этом ресурсе, но я все равно отвечу. Я создал архив с папками  "OBI_H", "OBI_R", "OBI_V" и файлами внутри, затем внес небольшие изменения в код чтобы он заработал. Основная ошибка была в том что прежде чем работать с директорией  нужно всегда убеждаться что она есть (в данном случае нужно создавать) ну и если я правильно понял логику то "in_obih" и т.п. идут без ".BANK" хотя не зная какой конктретно у Вас архив сложно судить, я судил по описанию в вопросе. Все правки прокомментированы в коде. Строчки которые не влияли на результат я убрал.

Возможно будет проще переименовывать распакованные директории чем файлы по отдельности (`os.rename(in_dir + '/OBI_H', mf_in_obis)`)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import patoolib
import os

today = datetime.now()
yesterday = today - timedelta(1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

path = 'D:/doc/ARHIW/'
rf = path + yesterday + '.rar'
in_dir = 'D:/doc/ARHIW/' + yesterday + '/IN/'
os.makedirs(in_dir) # создаем директорию
patoolib.extract_archive(rf, outdir=in_dir)

# убрано "+ yesterday"
in_obih = os.listdir(in_dir + '/OBI_H') # убрано расширение .BANK
in_obir = os.listdir(in_dir + '/OBI_R') # убрано расширение .BANK
in_obiw = os.listdir(in_dir  + '/OBI_V') # убрано расширение .BANK

mf_in_obis = in_dir + 'OBI_S.BANK/'
os.makedirs(mf_in_obis) # создаем директорию

for f in in_obih:
    # добавлен путь in_dir + '/OBI_H/'
    os.rename(in_dir + '/OBI_H/' + f, mf_in_obis + f)
```

после исполнения данного кода получаем такую картину

```
└── ARHIW
    ├── 30.06.2022
    │   └── IN
    │       ├── OBI_H
    │       ├── OBI_R
    │       │   ├── 1
    │       │   ├── 2
    │       │   └── 3
    │       ├── OBI_S.BANK
    │       │   ├── 1
    │       │   ├── 2
    │       │   └── 3
    │       └── OBI_V
    │           ├── 1
    │           ├── 2
    │           └── 3
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, извините за мою грубость может быть именно такой код никому и не понадобиться, но может какая нибудь строчка кода понадобиться.
Теперь про архив он состоит из из папок OBI_H.BANK, OBI_R.BANK, OBI_W.BANK и т.п. в них есть файлы с примерно вот такими именами OBI_20220702_154035_1706_1706 (без расширения), их надо распаковать в существующую папку например: D:\doc\ARHIW\02.07.2022\IN\OBI_S.BANK и поменять имя например OBI_R02_20220702_154035_1706_1706 (где **R** не меняется, а **02** это вчерашнее число) если что-то не уточнил скажите.

Comment: Все что Вы тут написали следовало добавлять в вопрос а не в комментарий уже после ответа, в любом случае я показал пример как распаковать и переместить файлы, если мой ответ не подходит, можете подождать еще вдруг кто-то захочет решить вашу конкретную задачу. Обычно вопросы стараются формулировать абстрактно, поверьте никому нет особого интереса OBI_H.BANK, OBI_R.BANK, OBI_W.BANK называются ваши папки или как-то еще, хороший код справится с любыми названиями и задачами. Плюс ко всему вопрос касается и распаковки архива а в заголовке про это ничего нет.